# Why am I getting this IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = [1,2,1,5]

b = [1,1,5]

c = [a[index] for index in b]  
print(c)
```

and I got this error:

```
IndexError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-e03093b57c86> in <module>

    2 b=[1,1,5]
      3 index=0
----> 4 c=[a[index] for index in b]
      5 c

<ipython-input-158-e03093b57c86> in <listcomp>(.0)

    2 b=[1,1,5]
      3 index=0
----> 4 c=[a[index] for index in b]
      5 c

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: When `index` is 5 `a[5]` would raise IndexError because length of `a` is 4

Comment: `a` has 4 elements.  The valid indices are `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.  So `b` should only contain those values.  But it contains a `5`, which is two elements past the end of `a`.  Either add more elements to `a` or remove the `5` from `b`.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you to use numpy array, with which the slicing is simplest. Have a look to https://numpy.org/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted to do this: (Slight modification of your code)

```
c = [a[index] for index in range(len(b))]
```

This iterates over the length of list b, which is [0, 1, 2] as len(b) = 3. And these are valid indexes for list a.

In the above implemenation, the list you are iterating over is [1, 1, 5]. And a[5] does not exist since list a has only 4 elements.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this is error is because your list `b` has got the number `5` and your list `a` is of length 5 and hence has a maximum index of 4, since indexing starts from 0.

So when you try and grab the value from list `a` at index `5`, there is no such value which results in the error: `list index out of range`